# Vue can't redirect to the same page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Im currently, making a form, where I have a button, "Save and add another" , what I do, I validate the data and if saving is a success I'm trying to redirect the user to the same page but its not working(example: from this page http://localhost:8080/#/add_new_entity to this page http://localhost:8080/#/add_new_entity).

So far i've tried this:

```
this.$router.push('/add-new-entity')
```

i get this error:

> NavigationDuplicated {_name: "NavigationDuplicated", name:
>   "NavigationDuplicated", message: "Navigating to current location
>   ("/add_new_entity") is not allowed", stack: "Error↵    at new
>   NavigationDuplicated (http://loca…voker
>   (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:135303:14)"}

And i know i could just refresh, but i have set in my router/index.js this: `router.replace({ path: '/dashboard', redirect: '/dashboard' })` so every time the page is refreshed it automaticaly redirects to /dashboard.

Any solutions out there?

EDIT: I still havent found a solution for that. Yes this catches the error `this.$router.push("/add-new-entry").catch(err => {}`) so I dont get the error message and can handle it, but I'm still not able to redirect to the same page.

Comment: Something like this.
this.$router.push({ path: '/add-new-entity'} )

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.$router.push("/add-new-entry").catch(err => {})